# mod rewrite matching a file in a subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

***Edit: Got it working, here's the final version***

```
RewriteCond $1 ^(.*?)/(.*)$
RewriteCond apps/%1/content/%2 -F
RewriteRule (.*) apps/%1/content/%2 [QSA,last]
```

***Edit: Original question at the bottom***

I have this close to working, here's a rule in my mod_rewrite

```
RewriteCond $1 ^(.*?)/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/johnsmith/apps/%1/content/%2 -f
RewriteRule (.*) apps/%1/content/%2 [QSA,last]
```

That will correctly route the request for

```
http://host/johnsmith/blog/css/style.css
```

to

```
/docroot/johnsmith/apps/blog/content/css/style.css
```

but, I need to hard code johnsmith into the .htaccess file under johnsmith.  Is it possible to use a relative path, and if not, is there are variable available to me so I know the current directory of .htaccess?

**Original question below**

Let's say I have an Apache web application with a docroot of /docroot
I have a css file located here:

```
/docroot/johnsmith/apps/blog/content/css/style.css
```

I want to retrieve this file with a request to

```
http://host/johnsmith/blog/css/style.css
```

The .htaccess file must be located in the johnsmith folder.  The following rule set causes an infinite redirect loop

```
RewriteCond ^(.*?)/(.*)$ apps/$1/content/$2 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*)$ apps/$1/content/$2 [QSA,last]
```

If I change it slightly, getting rid of the condition, I can go to a page which is a simple PHP script to print out the query string, which shows

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*)$ showquerystring.php?path=apps/$1/content/$2 [QSA,last]
```

path is equal to apps/blog/content/css/style.css, which is exactly what I expect it to be.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Also, the johnsmith folder can be named anything, and the .htaccess file inside of johnsmith shouldn't have to hard code johnsmith.

More succinctly, what I want to ask is:

Is there a variable available to mod_rewrite which will equal /blog/css/style.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond $1 ^(.*?)/(.*)$
RewriteCond apps/%1/content/%2 -F
RewriteRule (.*) apps/%1/content/%2 [QSA,last]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `/johnsmith/blog/css/style.css` redirects to `/johnsmith/apps/blog/content/css/style.css` which redirects to `/johnsmith/apps/apps/content/blog/content/css/style.css` etc. etc. This is because apache will repeat the rewrite process with the rewritten url.

Also I'm not sure the RewriteCond rule is correct.

So this is what I think it should be:

```
RewriteRule ^apps/ - [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/apps/$1/content/$2 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*)$ apps/$1/content/$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/apps/$1/content/$2 won't work because document root is /docroot, so Apache will be looking in /docroot/apps/. . . when the file is actually inside of /docroot/johnsmith/apps/. . .

Comment: Also, it won't infinite loop if it validly matches a file.